# dynamic data amchart

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, amcharts

I am trying to use the library amchart I tried to follow the examples of the site and it works with static data I want to know how to make graphs with dynamic data ie the database instance? who can help me
http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/stacked-column/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: http://amcharts-php.sourceforge.net/
I am sure there are more libraries or you can write one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in you servlet header define  `response.setContentType("application/json");`

create data in JSON format like

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("[");
            if(rs1.next()){
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"CH\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(1)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#FF0F00"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"USA\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(2)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#FF6600"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"UK\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(3)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#FF9E01"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"AU\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(4)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#FCD202"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"DK\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(5)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#F8FF01"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"PK\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(6)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#B0DE09"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"ML\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(7)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#04D215"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"JP\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(8)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#0D8ECF"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"IN\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(9)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#0D52D1"+"\"");
                sb.append("},");
                sb.append("{");
                sb.append("\"country\": \"TW\",");
                sb.append("\"visits\":\""+rs1.getString(10)+"\",");
                sb.append("\"color\":\""+"#2A0CD0"+"\"");
                sb.append("}");


                }
            sb.append("]");
```

then do `out.write(sb.toString());`

then in html file get data from request object  `var test=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);`

remember i have used Ajax in this ....